# Possible oversight in paper of Greene and Kleitman on chains in dominance order on partitions?

Tags: co.combinatorics, posets, partitions

This question is about a possible lacuna in a paper of Greene and Kleitman which Zarathustra Brady made me aware of.

The paper in question is "Longest Chains in the Lattice of Integer Partitions ordered by Majorization" (available online [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82493429.pdf)). In that paper they compute the length of the longest chain in the [dominance order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominance_order) on partitions, and more generally give an algorithm for finding the longest chain in any interval of dominance order.

In dominance order we have a cover relation $\lambda \gtrdot \mu$ if and only if $\mu$ is obtained from $\lambda$ by moving a single box in row $i$ to row $i+1$, or by moving a single box in column $i+1$ to column $i$. In the first case, Greene and Kleitman say that $\lambda \gtrdot \mu$ is an *H-step* (because, perhaps confusingly to modern readers, the box moved one unit horizontally according to their nonstandard scheme of drawing partitions with vertical parts- see Figure 2), and in the second case they say that $\lambda \gtrdot \mu$ is a *V-step* (because the box moved one unit vertically according to their depiction). Note, as the authors note, that it is possible that $\lambda \gtrdot \mu$ is both an H-step and a V-step (and in fact this is the source of the possible lacuna!).

Greene and Kleitman say that a chain $\lambda^0 > \lambda^1 > \cdots > \lambda^L$ is an *H-chain* if each step $\lambda^i > \lambda^{i+1}= \lambda^i \gtrdot \lambda^{i+1}$ is an H-step, and similarly say that the chain is a *V-chain* if each step $\lambda^i > \lambda^{i+1}= \lambda^i \gtrdot \lambda^{i+1}$ is a V-step. Furthermore, they say $\lambda^0 > \lambda^1 > \cdots > \lambda^L$ is an *HV-chain* if there is some index $i$ such that $\lambda^0 > \cdots > \lambda^i$ is an H-chain, and $\lambda^i > \cdots > \lambda^L$ is a V-chain.

In a crucial lemma of the paper, Lemma 3, they assert that if $\lambda = \lambda^0 > \lambda^1 > \cdots > \lambda^L = \mu$ is any chain in dominance order, then there exists some HV-chain between $\lambda$ and $\mu$ of length at least $L$. The argument they give is: we can assume each step in the chain is a cover relation; we can check that it is true for chains $\lambda_0 > \lambda_1 > \lambda_2$ of length 2; then by repeatedly applying this length 2 case we can convert any chain of length $L$ to an HV-chain of length at least $L$.

But this last point about repeatedly applying the length 2 case seems suspect, for the following reason. Suppose we have a length 3 chain $\lambda_0 > \lambda_1 > \lambda_2 > \lambda_3$ such that $\lambda_0 > \lambda_1$ is a V-step which is not an H-step, $\lambda_1 > \lambda_2$ is both a V- and H-step, and $\lambda_2 > \lambda_3$ is an H-step which is not a V-step. (This situation can arise: $(5,4,3,2) > (4,4,4,2) > (4,4,3,3) > (4,4,3,2,1)$.) Then the problem is that, from the perspective of length 2 subchains, things look fine: $\lambda_0 > \lambda_1 > \lambda_2$ is a V-chain, so is in particular an HV-chain; similarly $\lambda_1 > \lambda_2 > \lambda_3$ is an H-chain, so in particular is an HV-chain. But $\lambda_0 > \lambda_1 > \lambda_2 > \lambda_3$ is evidently not an HV-chain.

**Question**: Is this a real oversight in the paper of Greene-Kleitman? If so, is Lemma 3 indeed true, and can the proof be repaired?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Curtis Greene directly?

Comment: @TimothyChow: I have not.

Comment: This does look like case that was not considered in the proof.  It is not, though, a counterexample to the lemma (which I know you did not claim): The only H move from 5432 is (in their notation) $[4 \rightarrow 5]$ to 54311, then $[3 \rightarrow 4]$ to 54221, $[2 \rightarrow 3]$ to 53321, and finally $[1 \rightarrow 2]$ to 44321.  These are all simultaneously H and V steps, so call it an H-chain or a V-chain.